# Thread._wait_for_tstate_lock() never returns

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, deadlock

My program appears to run in a deadlock sometimes when I hit Ctrl+C. I'm trying to catch the keyboard interrupt and gracefully stop all running threads, but I'm not quite there yet.

I'm using a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`. To find the location of the deadlock, I'm using the [this receipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577334-how-to-debug-deadlocked-multi-threaded-programs/) from ActiveState.

Now, here's the full stacktrace:

```
# ThreadID: 4856
File: "c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\threading.py", line 884, in _bootstrap
  self._bootstrap_inner()
File: "c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "C:\Users\niklas\repos\nodepy\craftr\lib\utils\tracer.py", line 66, in run
  self.stacktraces()
File: "C:\Users\niklas\repos\nodepy\craftr\lib\utils\tracer.py", line 80, in stacktraces
  fout.write(stacktraces())
File: "C:\Users\niklas\repos\nodepy\craftr\lib\utils\tracer.py", line 28, in stacktraces
  for filename, lineno, name, line in traceback.extract_stack(stack):

# ThreadID: 6068
File: "c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
  "__main__", mod_spec)
File: "c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
  exec(code, run_globals)
File: "C:\Users\niklas\repos\nodepy\craftr\.nodepy_modules\.bin\craftr.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  sys.exit(nodepy.main.main())
File: "c:\users\niklas\repos\nodepy\nodepy\nodepy\main.py", line 103, in main
  ctx.load_module(ctx.main_module, do_init=False)
File: "c:\users\niklas\repos\nodepy\nodepy\nodepy\context.py", line 253, in load_module
  module.load()
File: "c:\users\niklas\repos\nodepy\nodepy\nodepy\loader.py", line 43, in load
  exec(code, vars(self.namespace))
File: "C:\Users\niklas\repos\nodepy\craftr\lib\main.py", line 110, in <module>
  sys.exit(main())
File: "C:\Users\niklas\repos\nodepy\craftr\lib\main.py", line 106, in main
  return backend.build_main(backend_args, session, module)
File: "C:\Users\niklas\repos\nodepy\craftr\lib\build_backends\default.py", line 194, in build_main
  executor.run(actions)
File: "C:\Users\niklas\repos\nodepy\craftr\lib\build_backends\default.py", line 171, in run
  self.wait()
File: "C:\Users\niklas\repos\nodepy\craftr\lib\build_backends\default.py", line 137, in wait
  self.pool.shutdown(wait=True)
File: "c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 144, in shutdown
  t.join()
File: "c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\threading.py", line 1056, in join
  self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
File: "c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\threading.py", line 1072, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
  elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
```

I can't make sense from this traceback. It appears that `Thread._wait_for_tstate_lock()` never returns (I checked multiple times, it always hangs at that line). There is no thread running other than the main thread (6068) and the tracer thread (4856).

I don't quite understand the implementation details of `threading.Thread`. What could cause `Thread._tstate_lock.acquire()` to block indefinitely?

---

*Update 2017/11/07 -- 01:45am CEWT*

This seems to happen when `pool.shutdown()` is called multiple times...

Answer (score 9):

I'm not 100% certain it's the reason you're seeing this as you are using Windows, but I encountered this on Linux with Python 3.6 in a similar scenario.

I was using `.shutdown()` on a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` and the program would seem to hang up.
Sometimes it would finally exit after 30-60 seconds.

Ctrl-C always resulted in a traceback showing it was sitting in `_wait_for_tstate_lock()`

**Note: in Python 3 a second Ctrl-C actually exits**

My problem occurred when the function submitted was using `time.sleep()` in a loop.

Looking at the `HtmlFileTracer` implementation in current nodepy code on github I see a similar scenario to what I was doing, (continuously loop and sleep for an interval unless some sort of flag was set)

Answer (score 0):

If you can (i.e. if your logic allows), set `daemon=True`:

- Subclass `ThreadPoolExecutor`;
- Override `_adjust_thread_count` method, setting `daemon=True` in the Thread creation.

This will ensure the program finishes even if some threads hang.