# Deadlock occurs when using multiprocessing.Pipe() in multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async function

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

**I try to use `multiprocessing.Pipe()` as communication tool in multi processes. But when I pass pipe into the `pool.apply_async()` as a parameter, there is a deadlock problem.Why?**

The code and output are:

```
# coding=utf-8
from multiprocess import pool
from multiprocessing import Pipe, Pool, set_start_method, get_context, Queue, Manager, Process
import time


def worker_process(name, _out_pipe, _in_pipe):

    # _out_pipe.close()

    for x in range(10):
        _in_pipe.send(name + ':' + str(x))
        print(name + ' send value :' + str(x))
        time.sleep(0.1)

    # _in_pipe.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    set_start_method('spawn')
    print(get_context())
    # with pool.Pool() as pool:
    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.apply_async(worker_process, ('son_p1', out_pipe, in_pipe))
        pool.apply_async(worker_process, ('son_p2', out_pipe, in_pipe))
        pool.apply_async(worker_process, ('son_p3', out_pipe, in_pipe))
        # pool.apply(worker_process, ('son_p1', out_pipe, in_pipe))
        # pool.apply(worker_process, ('son_p2', out_pipe, in_pipe))
        # pool.apply(worker_process, ('son_p3', out_pipe, in_pipe))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    while out_pipe.poll():
        print(out_pipe.recv())

    # in_pipe.close()
    # out_pipe.close()
```

```
Process ForkPoolWorker-2:
Process ForkPoolWorker-5:
Process ForkPoolWorker-1:
Process ForkPoolWorker-6:
Process ForkPoolWorker-8:
Process ForkPoolWorker-9:
Process ForkPoolWorker-7:
Process ForkPoolWorker-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zhaolong/PycharmProjects/pipEnvGrpc/pipe_example.py", line 34, in <module>
    pool.join()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 662, in join
    self._worker_handler.join()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 1011, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 1027, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
```

**But when I replace `multiprocessing.Pool()` to `multiprocess.pool.Pool()` or `multiprocessing.Pool().apply_async()` to `multiprocessing.Pool().apply()`, the program will run normally.Why?**

Comment: Looks related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47147328/thread-wait-for-tstate-lock-never-returns/) - **"My problem occurred when the function submitted was using time.sleep() in a loop."**, which is what you are doing inside your worker process.

Comment: [Issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue35608) on python bug tracker.

Comment: I have tried to remove time.sleep(), but the problem still exits.

Answer (score 2):

Try using spawn to create new processes instead of fork as per [this blog post](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/python-multiprocessing/).

```
from multiprocessing import set_start_method

if __name__ == '__main__':
    set_start_method("spawn")
    print(get_context())
```

Additionally, try to terminate your pool using finally. This has appeared as an issue [elsewhere](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1320).

```
try:
    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.apply_async(worker_process, ('son_p1', out_pipe, in_pipe))
        pool.apply_async(worker_process, ('son_p2', out_pipe, in_pipe))
        pool.apply_async(worker_process, ('son_p3', out_pipe, in_pipe))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    while out_pipe.poll():
        print(out_pipe.recv())
finally:
    pool.terminate()
```

Comment: I have modified the answer, please see if terminate works for you. FYI - your code runs on my linux machine in python3.8 with no issues.

Comment: Perhaps you could try putting a sleep timer in your main code, similar to what [this person did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212290/multiprocessing-queue-deadlocking-during-process-spawning).